# How to get results comparing only the day and month, ignoring the time of a timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to display some results (fields like name, description etc) from my database comparing a selected date with the timestamp of the rows in the database.

In my database, the field `start` has this form of timestamp `2013-07-30 23:00:00`.
When I search through a form, the `$selected` date has the same format like `2013-07-30 13:50:00`

However, I want to display results that match the same day and month, ignoring the time but I do not know how to do it using PDO statements. like comparing the `2013-07-30` only.

I have connected my database and can perform very basic queries through examples.

Thank you.

Comment: Use [`Date()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) to extract the date portion of both operands and compare the results.

Comment: I assume you want to use this on a select criteria so try adding this to your WHERE clause `WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Start, '%d-%m') = '31-12'`.
You can use DATE_FORMAT() to modify the data returned as well is you like `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Start, '%d/%m') as short_date FROM table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
$sh = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(`start`) = DATE(:start)');
$sh->bindValue(":start", $selected);
$sh->execute();
```

Comment: Than you for your answer. It is sure that it will help me. Can you check what I continued to this paste http://codepad.org/6aKI6kJ1 please?

Comment: Well, does it work? If it doesn't work, is there any error?

Comment: It works, thank you, I have accepted your answer. I have one question however. Suppose that an event starts on 2013-07-28 and ends on 2013-07-31. Selected date is 2013-07-30. Even though that the event is on going, it will no be displayed. How do we check if the selected date is between `start` and `end` ?

Comment: I believe you can use `DATE(:start) BETWEEN DATE(\`start\`) AND DATE(\`end\`)`

Comment: Note, using functions on the date column may prevent the database from utilizing existing indexes. I am not familiar with php, but *in general*, a more index friendly way of ignoring the time portion is:  `WHERE ColumnName >= {startDateAtMidnight} AND ColumnName < {dayAfterEndDateAtMidnight}`.

Answer (score 0):

Cast your DATETIME to DATE and then do your validation:

```
CAST(tablename.datetime AS DATE) as startDate
```